# Pydev is remembering discarded Python interpreters and discarding newly added ones

Tags: pydev

At one time I installed Python3.4 globally and a copy of 2.7 in a virtualenv folder.
Later I removed both, and installed Python 3.5 and a new copy of 2.7 in a different virtualenv directory.
Then proceeded to Preferences->PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreters to remove the *deleted* interpreters and add the *freshly installed* ones.
What happens now is that after closing and reopening Eclipse, the *new* are gone and the *old* are back. I can redo the delete/add operation but the next time: *Die kat kwam weer ...*

Answer (score 0):

Oops,
I should have re-checked before posting the question.
I checked the interpreters today, and everything is as it should be.
But there has been a PyDev update between my last try and yesterday.

Comment: Oops again!
I opened Eclispe this morning, and guess what ... yes _Die kat kwam weer_

Comment: The behaviour is erratic;
Some times it has the 'old' interpreters, some times it has the 'new' ones.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't using a different workspace at each time? I.e.: if you select a workspace just with 'c:' (without a slash in the end), it could use your current working dir (always make sure to put a slash in the end of the selected workspace -- there's a bug reporting this already at: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=316204.

Check if you have more than one .metadata in your directories (if you have, then it's likely you actually have more than workspace there)

Comment: Most of my workspaces are in C:\Users\Josy, except the ones installed by other applications.

Comment: And every workspace has it's own .metadata folder ...
The bug you refer to is from 2010? And is a corner case issue?

Comment: Well, if you've always specified the full path with a slash in the end, this shouldn't be the problem... (although the bug is still true today if you just pass something as `c:`, without putting a slash in the end).

Comment: No, I have never put the backslash at the end ...
If that would be a problem, would I then find .metadata folders elsewhere?